# Package ignore when running apt-get update

Tags: 12.04, server, apt, repository

I'm trying to install Centrify Express on Ubuntu Server 12.04. I know there are several ways of doing this, but I've found that the most straightforward way is to add the Canonical archive repository and then `apt-get install` it. This has worked for me for the last 10 months or so on at least 12 systems.

Now after I added the repository and I run `apt-get update`, I see that the repository is ignored, and therefore I cannot install Centrify this way.

This is the apt-get update line:

```
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en
```

Why is it ignored, and is there actually a manual way of updating a specific repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of a problem in the centrifydc package as indicated here on their forums:
http://community.centrify.com/t5/DirectControl-Express-for-UNIX/Broken-new-centrifydc-package-for-ubuntu-12-04-LTS/td-p/12010/page/2

> Thanks for your patience on this. We are working with canonical to have these packages available soon, I don't have a confirmed date but we are making progress.
>
> We hope to have it ready within a week and we will update the thread as soon as we have something more definitive.

So this should be resolved in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Centrify Express, Is a free Active Directory Integration and single sign-on for Ubuntu - Centrify Express is the No. 1 choice of IT professionals for Active Directory-based authentication and single sign-on to cross-platform systems.

To install, just click it [**Centrify Express** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](http://www.centrify.com/express/free-active-directory-tools-for-linux-mac.asp#agents), just scroll down until you see the download for Ubuntu.

For more information on how to install .tar.gz in Ubuntu, see [How to install a .tar.gz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Or, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ oneiric partner"
```

Centrify Express Now Baked into Ubuntu Repository.  Once you type the command above, and it finishes, just search for it using the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: i don't have a software center or can use your method... it's a server version

and it's ignoring the repositories i added like you said, but i always replaced "oneiric" with "precise" since it concerns 12.04....

Comment: I have modified the installation link, where it says Certify Express, so you can download it from the source.  Let me know if it works. Thanks

Comment: I know that works. That's not my problem, i can install centrify, my question only regards the apt-get method... and actually just what to do with any repositories that might be ignored in the future

Answer (score 0):

Not every repository provides translation-data for localization, that's not a problem at all.

E.g. this is an output of one of my systems:

```
sudo apt-get update|grep canonical
OK   http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg
OK   http://archive.canonical.com precise Release
OK   http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages
OK   http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-de_DE
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-de
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en
```

So as far as an `sudo apt-get install centrifydc` does not give any error, your're fine!